# Finding Max Number in Vector of Strings

Tags: r

I have a vector with the following info:

```
"CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-**16**.txt"
"CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-**4**.txt"
```

As we can see, those two elements in the vector have both numbers and characters, so what I want to do is to get the biggest number (only the bolded numbers), the elements structure will not change just the numbers will change.

Anyone knows how to figure this out?

The outcome should be 16 for this example.

Comment: This is not the best description of the problem I believe. You really want the largest number preceding `.txt` from a list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @gopala's interpretation is right and you want the largest numbers preceding .txt, the following `gsub` function will pull it out:

```
temp <- c("CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-16.txt", 
          "CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-4.txt")

max(as.numeric(gsub("^.*-([0-9]+)\\.txt$", "\\1", temp)))
```

Here are the components of the solution:

- The`max` function is self-explanatory
- `as.numeric` coerces an argument (typically, a vector) to numeric type, which we feed to `max`.

The meat of the solution is `gsub`, which takes a regular expression (her, "^.*-([0-9]+)\.txt$"), a substitution string (here, "\1"), and a string vector.

The regular expression "^.*-([0-9]+)\.txt$" says "^" from the beginning, ".*" match anything up to "-" a hyphen. "()" capture [0-9]+ numerical digits, 0 through 9, match exactly ".txt" at the end "$". The "\" is an escape and tells the regex engine to treat "." as literal dot, not the any character in the beginning.

The replacement "\1" says return the first captured "()" subexpression, which is our digits, "[0-9]+".

Regular expressions are amazing tools that are available in many pieces of software, this is my favorite [regex site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

If the vector contains elements that don't match the pattern and you want to ignore them, you can add the na.rm argument to `max` as follows:

```
temp <- c("CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-16.txt", 
          "CCP--TODAS(00)--MAMOLGUR (20151015)-4.txt",
          "PPS--TODAS--MAMOLGUR 20151128-116 -Cuba y San Jose")

max(as.numeric(gsub("^.*-([0-9]+)\\.txt$", "\\1", temp)), na.rm=T)
```

This produces a warning regarding missing values, but still returns the correct answer.

Comment: It returns `6` but the correct result should be `16`.

Comment: Thanks once again, @elevendollar. I added a hyphen to the regex which forced the greedy match to calm down.

Comment: Thank you!! It Works perfectly fine however, I would like to know how it Works, Could you please explain how it does it please?  And Also If it happens to contain errors how do I handle that... The errors are caused by files that do not follow the right structure for instance:  "PPS--TODAS--MAMOLGUR 20151128-116 -Cuba y San Jose "

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it!  Can you also please answer how to handle the error thing?

Comment: I added another block of code with an error handling method that ignores non-matches (after complaining).